# javaScript .bind() does not returns a new function that, when called, will have 'this' equal to the arg I passed

Tags: javascript

I have below code.

```
var person1 = {
    fname: 'Cristiano',
    lname: 'Ronaldo',
    getName: function() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
    }
}

var person2 = {
    fname: 'Luka',
    lname: 'Modric',
    getName: function() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
    }
}


var logname = function() {
    console.log(this.getName());
}.bind(person1); // not working as expected when .bind() here !!!


var newlogname1 = logname.bind(person1);
newlogname1(); // prints 'Cristiano Ronaldo'

var newlogname2 = logname.bind(person2);

newlogname2(); // prints 'Cristiano Ronaldo'
```

```js
var person1 = {
        fname: 'Cristiano',
        lname: 'Ronaldo',
        getName: function() {
            return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
        }
    }

    var person2 = {
        fname: 'Luka',
        lname: 'Modric',
        getName: function() {
            return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
        }
    }


    var logname = function() {
        console.log(this.getName());
    }.bind(person1); // not working as expected when .bind() here !!!


    var newlogname1 = logname.bind(person1);
    newlogname1(); // prints 'Cristiano Ronaldo'

    var newlogname2 = logname.bind(person2);

    newlogname2(); // prints 'Cristiano Ronaldo'
```

But if I change the below code snippet, it will work as I expected.

```
var logname = function() {
    console.log(this.getName());
};
```

```js
var person1 = {
    fname: 'Cristiano',
    lname: 'Ronaldo',
    getName: function() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
    }
}

var person2 = {
    fname: 'Luka',
    lname: 'Modric',
    getName: function() {
        return this.fname + ' ' + this.lname;
    }
}


var logname = function() {
    console.log(this.getName());
};

var newlogname2 = logname.bind(person2);
newlogname2();

var newlogname1 = logname.bind(person1);
newlogname1();
```

What is this behavior ? What happens when I `.bind()` just in the declaration part of it. Can't I change what `this` supposed to mean when the function runs if I do like that.

Comment: In the first example, `logname` is already bound with `person1`. *"the bind() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(), **which cannot be overridden**."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bind()` only works if the `function` you're binding isn't already *bound*:

```js
function f() {
  console.log(this.a)
}

const f_1 = f.bind({a: 1}) // As expected
const f_2 = f.bind({a: 2}) // -Ditto-
const f_2_3 = f_2.bind({a: 3}) // f_2 already bound, can't .bind() to other object

f_1()
f_2()
f_2_3()

/** Check if function is bound, as per @str's comment */
function isBound(fun) {
  return !('prototype' in fun)
}

console.log(
  isBound(f),
  isBound(f_1)
)
```

*Update*: Added way to check if `function` is already *bound*, as per [@str's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56098632/javascript-bind-does-not-returns-a-new-function-that-when-called-will-have/56098658#comment98832391_56098658) below

Comment: Do we have a way to find whether a function is already bound or not ?

Comment: @prime - Sadly, no, not without calling it, and that only works if it uses `this` and we can tell from the call what `this` it used.

Comment: According to the [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype.bind), "*Function objects created using `Function.prototype.bind` [...] do not have a prototype property.*" So you might use that for a check.